# Directshow GMFBridge saving multiple clips to a single file

Tags: vb.net, directshow, directshow.net

Here is the main body of code that I am using with GMFBridge. I have an sg (sourcegraph) and rg (rendergraph) object that keeps the filtergraph, mediaseeking, etc., in the one place so I can release them.

When I run this it renders the clips to the screen perfectly. Seeking to each clip and playing properly. I get the right sequence of event codes in the "Bridge End of Segment" that I expect (i.e. one BEOS message per clip).

However, When I try to write the clips out to an AVI file, I only ever get the first clip. I also only ever get one "Bridge End of Segment" message. The code that is commented out in the "with rg" section is what I use to write to an AVI file. If I check the graphs in GraphEdit they are connected properly.

I have also added the code for the "Bridge End of Segment" message at the bottom.

This is driving me crazy. I must be missing something really simple. Any help appreciated.

```
        ' Get the source media file...
        If openfile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            If Bridge Is Nothing Then
                Bridge = New GMFBridgeController
                Bridge.AddStream(True, eFormatType.eAny, True)
                'Bridge.AddStream(False, eFormatType.eMuxInputs, False)
                Bridge.SetBufferMinimum(200)
            End If

            With sg
                ' Create graph to use. 
                .graph = New FilterGraph

                ' Create other interfaces. Don't need them all but am 
                ' experimenting. 
                .mediacontrol = DirectCast(.graph, IMediaControl)
                .mediaseeking = DirectCast(sg.graph, IMediaSeeking)
                .mediaeventex = DirectCast(.graph, IMediaEventEx)
                .mediaeventex.SetNotifyWindow(Me.Handle, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, Nothing)

                ' Create the graphedit entry so I can see what I've made. 
                .rotentry = New DsROTEntry(.graph)

                ' If not using bridge comment out this line. 
                sg.filter = Bridge.CreateSourceGraph(openfile.FileName, sg.graph)
            End With

            With rg
                .graph = DirectCast(New FilterGraph, IFilterGraph2)
                .capgraph = New CaptureGraphBuilder2
                .capgraph.SetFiltergraph(.graph)

                ''''' CODE THAT I USE TO WRITE TO AN AVI FILE
                '''''Dim aviDest As IBaseFilter = New AviDest()
                '''''.graph.AddFilter(aviDest, "AVI Mux")
                '''''Dim writer As IBaseFilter = New FileWriter
                '''''.graph.AddFilter(writer, "File Writer")
                '''''Dim filewriter As IFileSinkFilter2 = DirectCast(writer, IFileSinkFilter2)
                '''''filewriter.SetFileName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\StatsManager\Videos\momtest.avi", Nothing)

                ' Create the render graph ...
                .filter = Bridge.CreateRenderGraph(sg.filter, .graph)

                ' Ancillary control interfaces...
                .mediaseeking = DirectCast(.graph, IMediaSeeking)
                .mediacontrol = DirectCast(.graph, IMediaControl)

                ' Let me see the graph in GraphEdit.
                .rotentry = New DsROTEntry(.graph)
            End With

            ' Add my list of offsets...
            For Each obj As Object In listOffsets.Items
                clipoffsets.Add(Val(obj.ToString))
            Next

            ' How long to play the clips for...
            clipplaytime = Val(txtClipTime.Text)

            ' Just so I know what video I chose. 
            Me.Text = "Video:" + Path.GetFileName(openfile.FileName)
        End If
```

This is the code that handles the "End of Segment" message.....

```
Public Sub Bridge_OnEndOfSegment() Handles Bridge.OnEndOfSegment
    Try
        log("BEOS")
        clipindex = clipindex + 1
        If clipindex = clipoffsets.Count Then          ' this is the proper version :)
            log("End of clips")
            clipindex = 0
            If chkLoop.Checked = False Then
                sg.mediacontrol.Stop()
                rg.mediacontrol.Stop()
            Else
                log("....looping")
                SeekToClip(clipoffsets(clipindex))
            End If
        Else
            log("Moving to clip:" + clipoffsets(clipindex).ToString)
            SeekToClip(clipoffsets(clipindex))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        log("ERROR in EOS :" + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do all clips have exactly the same format (including resolution, sample rate)?

Comment: Yes, they are actually all clips from the same video so no changes of any sort.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong just eyeballing your code. Do you want to post more of the code (SeekToClip for example) or contact me offline and I'll post an answer here for everyone when we've sorted it?

Comment: Hi Geraint, That would be great. I'll do that and hopefully get it sorted. Very happy to share the code.